# How to solve Failed to find target with hash string 'android-27' in: C:\Users\iampr\AppData\Local\Android\sdk while launching app in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

PS F:\flutter\projects>

```
flutter doctor
```

> Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):

[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.0.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.371], locale en-US)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)

[√] Android Studio (version 3.2)

[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.30.1)

[√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!

PS F:\flutter\projects\demoflutter>

```
flutter run
```

Using hardware rendering with device Android SDK built for x86. If you get graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with
"--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...

> Initializing gradle...2.7s
>
> **Resolving dependencies...**

- Error running Gradle:
  ProcessException: Process "F:\flutter\projects\demoflutter\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

> Configure project :app
>
> Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 in C:\Users\iampr\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\licenses
>
> License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 accepted.
>
> Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 (revision: 28.0.3)".
>   "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 (revision: 28.0.3)" ready.
>   Installing Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 in
>
> C:\Users\iampr\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\28.0.3
>   "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 (revision: 28.0.3)" complete.
>   "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 (revision: 28.0.3)" finished.
>
> Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 27 in C:\Users\iampr\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\licenses
>   License for package Android SDK Platform 27 accepted.
>
> Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 27 (revision: 3)".
>   "Install Android SDK Platform 27 (revision: 3)" ready.
>
> Installing Android SDK Platform 27 in
>
> C:\Users\iampr\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-27
>   "Install Android SDK Platform 27 (revision: 3)" complete.
>   "Install Android SDK Platform 27 (revision: 3)" finished.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'F:\flutter\projects\demoflutter\android\build.gradle' line: 24
- What went wrong:

> A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
>
> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   Failed to find target with hash string 'android-27' in: C:\Users\iampr\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full
  insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 21s
  Command: F:\flutter\projects\demoflutter\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
PS F:\flutter\projects\demoflutter>

**this is my gradle file**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.demoflutter"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

[click here to view android sdk image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b82gx.png)

[platforms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUnyq.png)

[build-tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhlDy.png)

Comment: I think it could be a problem with your `targetSdkVersion`. Could you please post your `build.gradle` file in your `./android directory`. If you have `targetSdkVersion = 'android-27'` replace with `targetSdkVersion = 27`

Comment: sure i will update it now

Comment: hey now i added my gradle file just check it now

Comment: That's look fine...

Comment: i will trying this for about nearly 4 days but still im not found the soluction so please help me if you know

Comment: Check if you have the `SDK 27` **installed** and if not download it or try to change 27 to 28 this way `compileSdkVersion = 28`

Comment: It's really wired. Can I suggest you to download AS and try to open the `./android` project with AS and build from there? All looks fine in your files, but AS ha full of suggestions and could even help you install needed components, helping you figuring out whats wrong.

Comment: i have already tried in AS but no changes the same error will be repeated..

Comment: Can you post the directory listing of these folder? `C:\Users\iampr\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools` and `C:\Users\iampr\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms`

Comment: hey i provided a image link for both platform and build-tools so kindly check it out.

Comment: And if you open the ./android project with AS and go to `File -> Project Structure` and choose `app` under module. In `compile Sdk Version` what you see? Sorry but, all seems fine. So I need to  ask you all that things

Comment: Thank you man, finally i got it ..thanks for your great solution and your co-operation without you i con't make it possible.. Credits goes to "shadowsheep"

i here by attach my answer screenshots below

Comment: Hey! Glad to know! ^_^ Looking forward to see what was the issue among all our trials.

Comment: thank you so much man..look at these following images:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just follow these four steps this is what worked for me..!**

[step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STZPE.png)

[step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ddLC.png)

[step 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4hJ7.png)

[step 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaZm2.png)

[that's all this is the output..!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6JYz.png)

Comment: Good job! Just to know. Which version of AS do you have?

Comment: Android Studio  3.2.1 - which is  the latest version.

Comment: I am really surprised as these settings are not at all required and they remain as defaults for all the projects. Glad, that it resolved the issue. thanks for teaching me something new.Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change from Project structure -> Modules -> Properties the compile sdk version.

I had the same error and changed to 28 and it worked.

[image]